# trouble with calculating

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

i am currently trying to do the volume of a sphere but when i run my program it gives me the wrong answer. here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)calculate 
{
   double radiusNum = [radius.text doubleValue];
   double ansNum = 4/3 * 3.14159 * (radiusNum * radiusNum * radiusNum);

   NSString *ans = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.4f Units^3", ansNum];
   answer.text = ans;
}
```

could you please tell me how to fix it an d what i did wrong.
p.s i am using Xcode 4 and thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post an example of an incorrect value? Your math looks right, and your string formatting looks OK, too. If you stop in the debugger, is ansNum correct? If so, maybe there's a problem with how you're formatting the display of the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is logical mistake.
The method should be as follows:

```
-(IBAction)calculate 
{ 
  double radiusNum = [radius.text doubleValue]; 
  double ansNum = (4 * 3.14159 * (radiusNum * radiusNum * radiusNum))/3;

  NSString *ans = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.4f Units^3", ansNum]; 
  answer.text = ans; 
}
```

The order of computing was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

4/3 will be an integer operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
double radiusNum = [radius.text doubleValue];
 double ansNum = (pow(radiusNum, 3)*4/3)*3.1415927;

 NSString *ans = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.4f Units^3", ansNum];
    NSLog(ans);
```